# How do i change the color of the drop-down List of spinner items in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner on action bar, when touch the spinner image, the drop-down appears and it has black color, all rows of the spinner items are of black color, i want to change the color of the spinner rows, how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View v, int pos, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.tilte_lite_black);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                    }

                });
```